# How to generate UPI address from Bank account and ifsc code

Tags: android, bank, upi

I want to made payment via upi app using bank details with android upi deep linking..

I tried below format

accountNumber@ifsccode.ifsc.npci

this actually opening app and also going till payment screen but payment is not happening

ERROR: Payment faild

Please help me ..

Comment: Which app? 
https://www.labnol.org/upi/